# how to use MySQL DB for EGmap extension in Yii

Tags: mysql, google-maps, yii

for example i have a MySQL database that contains latitude and longitude, how do I call these coordinates to be displayed in the map ? anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question and information are a bit unclear, these are my assumptions:

1. I assume that you have followed the instruction correctly to install the EGMap
   extension into your yii application.
2. You want to place a marker at the said coordinates (latitude &
   longitude).

Sample codes: (please adjust to fit your database tables and columns at the lines
commented as "// Get LatLong from table Location"). Place this straight into your view file example: protected/views/site/index.php

```
<!-- other html codes here -->
<div id="map-container">
<?php
// Get LatLong from table Location
$location=Location::model()->findByPk(1);
$latitude = $location->latitude;
$longitude = $location->longitude;

Yii::import('ext.gmap.*');

$gMap = new EGMap();
$gMap->setJsName('map');
$gMap->zoom = 10;
$mapTypeControlOptions = array(
    'sensor'=>true,
    'position'=> EGMapControlPosition::LEFT_BOTTOM,
    'style'=>EGMap::MAPTYPECONTROL_STYLE_DROPDOWN_MENU
);
// Map settings
$gMap->mapTypeControlOptions= $mapTypeControlOptions;
$gMap->setWidth(800);
$gMap->setHeight(600);
$gMap->setCenter($latitude, $longitude);

// Prepare icon
$icon = new EGMapMarkerImage("http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/gazstation.png");
$icon->setSize(32, 37);
$icon->setAnchor(16, 16.5);
$icon->setOrigin(0, 0);
// Prepare marker
$marker = new EGMapMarker($latitude, $longitude, array('title' => 'Gas Station','icon'=>$icon));
$gMap->addMarker($marker);

$gMap->renderMap();
?>
</div>
<!-- other html codes here -->
```